# Selection Bias in Linear Regression Model

Tags: regression, selection-bias

[image]

[image]

Can anyone explain what is the difference between $(\bar{e_1} - \bar{e_0}) $ and ${E(\bar{e_1 }) - E(\bar{e_2 })}$?

I know they are both selection bias, but what are the differences?

Why do we say that we allow individuals to self-select into treatment and control then ${E(\bar{e_1 }) - E(\bar{e_2 })}$
is the selection bias? What is the selection bias if individuals are not allowed to self-select into the groups?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.